# Unable to use BeautifulSoup, ModuleNotFoundError but "Requirement already satisfied"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've installed beautifulsoup4 using pip and pip3. When I run my Python shell, I get:

> > > import bs4
> > > print(bs4)
> > > <module 'bs4' from '/Users/myUserName/Desktop/Dev/virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py'>

But when I try the same thing in IDE (Sublime), I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I'm stumped, I downloaded pandas right after and it worked just fine in my IDE. Any tips to fix this problem? Or do I just try another web scraping tool?

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the same virtual environment?

Comment: pls run this command on `cmd` & let me know what output you got?  `pip3 show beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Yes I did, and I ran the command and got:                     Name: beautifulsoup4
Version: 4.11.1
Summary: Screen-scraping library
Home-page: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/
Author: Leonard Richardson
Author-email: leonardr@segfault.org
License: MIT
Location: /Users/jimmyfl0/Desktop/Dev/mine/the_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: soupsieve
Required-by: django-bootstrap-v5, django-bootstrap4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows that you are in a different interpreter. What you can do is to `append` the **path** of beautifulsoup4 into your working environment before importing.

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("/Users/jimmyfl0/Desktop/Dev/mine/the_venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages")

import bs4
```

Comment: Thank you! I found a solution by manually moving the folders into where Sublime was looking, but thanks anyway for your help! I tried to upvote but I dont have any rep lol

Comment: You are welcome @JimmyFl0. **Note:** *With the approach you took, you are likely to have that same import error if you have other scripts somewhere with **import bs4***

Comment: Thanks again, just switched over to your method!