# ModuleError: No module named pptx found

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am writing a python code for merging ppts. It takes the location of the 2 ppts, merges them and puts the merged ppt formed in the folder given by user. The code used is:

```
import sys
from pptx import Presentation
#import Aspose.Words.License
#import aspose.slides as a_slides
#import os
#import win32com.client

def merge_powerpoint_ppts(pres_loc1, pres_loc2, output_loc):
    p1 = open(pres_loc1)
    pres1 = Presentation(p1)
    p2 = open(pres_loc2)
    pres2 = Presentation(p2)  
    for slide in pres2.slides:
        for lide in pres1.slides:
            if slide.shape.title.text == lide.shape.title.text:
                  pres1.slides.add_Clone(slide)
    pres1.save(output_loc)
    p1.close()
    p2.close()
```

When I try to debug the code, I get the following:
[Error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yID2l.png

I have already installed the module pptx on my system and it is updated, but I am still getting this error.

Comment: The Error Image is not showing

Comment: Does this answer  your question?  [ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73425183/19290081)

Answer (score 0):

#### `First` if you have a folder named Presentation or pptx change it cause this could happen because of  naming confusion of files or folder and python modules

#### `Secondly` make sure you use the correct python interpreter or env where you install pptx in in

###### `last Option` uninstall pptx and write  the following command

`conda install -c conda-forge python-pptx`

Comment: The last option is not working for me, since I am not working in anaconda, there is no folder named Presentation or pptx, and I am using the correct py env

Comment: @SharvariMittal try run `pip install python-pptx` to install Pillow

Comment: if there is no solution i recommend install anaconda or check this https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/200

Comment: I have done that already. @MohamedFathallah, even then the error persists

Comment: @SharvariMittal okay, the last option is to uninstall all pythons in your device and install python throw anaconda this will work 100%.

Comment: Thanks, @MohamedFathallah, I solved the problem by using python 3.7 instead of python 3.3